# Trouble with finding closest date to today from database dates

Tags: python, django, postgresql, view

Using django/models/views, I'm trying to return the closest date to today from a database where one of the columns is a date. (2016/03/25)

The code I have right now to find the date is:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().date()
statement_list = StatementData.objects.filter(date__gt=now()).reverse()[0]
```

I got this from another stackoverflow question but it returns an error:

```
datetime.date' object is not callable
```

The field name for the dates is "date", i dont know if that is a problem or not.

Basically what I want is:

```
SELECT * FROM StatementDate WHERE date = "(this is the date that is closest to today)"
```

I also want the next closest date to that date... but I believe I can get that once I get the first query done.

Look I know this is prob a duplicate but I cant seem to figure out the other answers and I cant post a comment on them to figure it out. So... if you could point me to the exact answered question or help me out here I would really appreciate it.

Comment: datetime.datetime' object is not callable is what is now returned... Do you need more code?

Comment: How you import `datetime` ?

Comment: yes `date` is a data type - if you want column with this name, you should makedjango to double quote it

Comment: now() replace it with now.

Comment: I import with "import datetime", however my date in postgres/admin panel is 2015-12-31. and I'm getting a "expected string or buffer error"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().date()
statement_list = StatementData.objects.filter(date__gt=now()).reverse()[0]
```

1. remove `()` from `date`
2. remove the `()` from the second line
3. You can just use `.last()` instead of `reverse()[0]`

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().date
statement_list = StatementData.objects.filter(date__gt=now).last()
```

---

To explain the actual error(s) your getting, by adding the brackets, python thinks you are trying to call methods with the name `date` and then later on `now`, in which these, are not methods(callables). They are just objects.

Comment: This cleared the error, so thank you for that. But it returned no results so I have to figure that out for now. But Thank you for the answer!!

Comment: @DenisAngell - No worries, small hint `__gt` may not be the correct thing to use.. (and it may not be in the correct order)

Comment: Yeah, like I said I copied it from someone else's answer. So now I'm getting a "expected string or buffer" error... Is this because the date is in the incorrect format?

Comment: My date on admin panel is in 2015-12-31 format... I think this is why

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply try :

```
 select * from StatementDate order by now()-date limit 1
```

Comment: The op is using django orm, not raw postgresql